# Incremental refresh of 1 day scheduled to run every week at 10AM

Tags: powerbi

I am looking at a dataset which has the fact table configured for Incremental refresh. Store rows is configured as: last 1 year. Refresh rows is configured as: last of 1 day.

The dataset is scheduled to refresh every week on Monday 10AM.

Is this a valid configuration? Because when the schedule runs on Monday 10AM, it will only pull data from previous day (last 1 day)?

Comment: If it runs every Monday and handle only Sunday's data, what about data from Monday to Saturday?

Comment: Actually it looks like it's pulling data only for Monday 00:00 to 09:59